# Make a legend for a ROC curve with colors

Tags: r, ggplot2, roc

I've made a ROC curve of 4 different models. This is the code I used:

```
auc_model1 <- round(auc(roc_model1), 3)
auc_model2 <- round(auc(roc_model2), 3)
auc_model3 <- round(auc(roc_model3), 3)
auc_model4 <- round(auc(roc_model4), 3)

legend_labels <- c(paste('Model 1 (AUC=', auc_model1, ')'),
                   paste('Model 2 (AUC=', auc_model2, ')'),
                   paste('Model 3 (AUC=', auc_model3, ')'),
                   paste('Model 4 (AUC=', auc_model4, ')'))

data <- data.frame(fpr = roc_model1$specificities, tpr = roc_model1$sensitivities, model = "Model 1")
data <- rbind(data, data.frame(fpr = roc_model2$specificities, tpr = roc_model2$sensitivities, model = "Model 2"))
data <- rbind(data, data.frame(fpr = roc_model3$specificities, tpr = roc_model3$sensitivities, model = "Model 3"))
data <- rbind(data, data.frame(fpr = roc_model4$specificities, tpr = roc_model4$sensitivities, model = "Model 4"))


ggplot(data, aes(x = 1 - fpr, y = tpr, color = model)) +
  geom_line(size = 0.8) +
  labs(x = "False Positive Rate", y = "True Positive Rate", color = "Model") +
  geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 1, linetype = "dashed") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottomright") +
  guides(color = guide_legend(title = NULL, label.position = "bottom", label.hjust = 1, override.aes = list(color = c("blue", "red", "green", "purple")))) +
  annotate("text", x = 0.7, y = 0.08, label = paste(legend_labels, collapse = "\n"), hjust = 0, vjust = 0)
```

This is the result. I can't know which model is which without coloring the legend:

[image]

Comment: You don't need to add an annotation like that to create a legend. It should appear automatically. What do you see if you just remove the last two lines of your code?

Comment: @AllanCameron The legend disappears completely.

Comment: There is no `legend.position` named `bottomright`. It has to be one of "none", "left", "right", "bottom", "top"  or a two-element numeric vector.

Comment: Try changing to `legend.position = c(0.8, 0.2)`

Answer (score 1):

If you are not against installing and using `pROC` package

I think it is more simple way to plot ROC curve.
Here a toy example

```
library(pROC)
library(MASS) # for the Pima data
data(Pima.tr)
mod1=glm(type ~ age,data=Pima.tr,family ="binomial")
mod2=glm(type ~ age + bmi,data=Pima.tr,family = "binomial")
Pima.tr$pred1= predict(mod1,type = "response") 
Pima.tr$pred2= predict(mod2,type = "response")

plot.roc(Pima.tr$type,Pima.tr$pred1,col="red",
         print.auc=TRUE)
plot.roc(Pima.tr$type,Pima.tr$pred2,col="green",
         add=TRUE,
         print.auc.x=0.5,
         print.auc.y=0.45,
        print.auc=TRUE )
legend("bottomright", legend=c("model1", "model2"), col=c("red", "green"), lwd=2)
```

[image]